# Laravel 8 - Pagination not showing numbers

Tags: laravel

I am trying to do a pagination and it works. But in the pagination I am only getting

```
« Previous Next »
```

How to do pagination with laravel so that i can see number pagination

```
< 1 2 3 >
```

Answer (score 1):

you can check that in the In `providers/AppServiceProvider` this line is added

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me, it was displaying like this => "pagination.previous pagination.next"